# What is the correct place to install Git from?

Tags: git

Just started using eGit with Eclipse projects on Windows platform. Feel need to go revise git basics  to fill in gaps in understanding.

I'm going to install git on my home pc and am looking for the simplest install/uninstall process. Bearing in mind after a while will be switching to use eGit in Eclipse.

For this purpose, which is the correct place to install git from?

1. The [official build on Git website](https://git-scm.com/download/win)

Git for Windows, which I understand is separate from Git.

Have scanned thru some of the info on https://gitforwindows.org. And install process looks complicated.

2. Automated installation using Git Chocolatey package, which I understand is community maintained, doesn't seem very easy either, if just want learn basics of git.

May use GitHub in future but current security policy working to mandates source on local machines rather than using cloud, so not allowed to use GitHub.

Also don't need to instal from source.

Comment: Both https://git-scm.com/download/win and https://gitforwindows.org/ use exaclty the same install-package. Installation is easy for both: "download, execute, accept defaults (for starters)". Regarding Egit: EGit is "only" a plugin for Eclipse which i'm using daily. But I could not live without the "plain" git commandline client to do more complex things. This cannot be done with Egit/Jgit.

Comment: @A.H. Many thanks - your comment was v. helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should refer to Git's [official documentation](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-Installing-Git), which already mostly covers your question.  Beyond this, on Windows I usually install Git in the `Program Files` folder, in a folder called something like `Git`.  I usually want the standard installation, even if I am using other Git plugins, because the installation comes with things like the Git Bash, which are useful.  Then, I refer my other tools which consume Git to this installation.  For example, I would configure IntelliJ to point to this Git installation in `Program Files`.

Comment: thanks for the tips about installing Git, using other Git plugins and configuration.

Comment: Do you think it's also worth enabling and installing the unix subsystem?

Answer (score 1):

Since I love to have portable apps (no installation, no deinstallation, just copy them where you want and delete them if you don't want them anymore), i consequently use portable git. For Windows goto https://git-scm.com/download/win and download the "64-Bit Git for Windows portable". Then you'll have everything you need including a very well equipped bash shell - and that all without any installation, just unzip to anywhere you want and run "git-bash.exe".